# How to sort a file by duration column?

Tags: sort, timestamps

How to sort a file containing below? (s=second, h=hour, d=day m=minute)

```
1s
2s
1h
2h
1m
2m
2s
1d
1m
```

Comment: Are there always only whole numbers, nothing like `1h30m40s` or `1.30h`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk '{ unitvalue=$1; }; 
    /s/ { m=1 }; /m/ { m=60 }; /h/ { m=3600 }; /d/ { m=86400 }; 
    { sub("[smhd]","",unitvalue); unitvalue=unitvalue*m; 
    print unitvalue " " $1; }' input |
        sort -n | awk '{ print $2 }'
1s
2s
2s
1m
1m
2m
1h
2h
1d
```

Answer (score 6):

This an extension of [MiniMax’ answer](/a/398241/47852) that can handle a broader range of duration value like `1d3h10m40s`.

GNU Awk program (stored in `parse-times.awk` for the sake of this answer):

```awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{
  FPAT = "[0-9]+[dhms]";
  duration["s"] = 1;
  duration["m"] = 60;
  duration["h"] = duration["m"] * 60;
  duration["d"] = duration["h"] * 24;
}

{
  t=0;
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    t += $i * duration[substr($i, length($i))];
  print(t, $0);
}
```

Invocation:

```sh
gawk -f parse-times.awk input.txt | sort -n -k 1,1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

---

### Multi-column input

If your input contains multiple columns you’ll have to resort to other means. The following code uses a function to parse time expressions and appends the result as a new column:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
# Given a time expression like "1d3h10m40s",  returns its duration in seconds.
# If the expression doesn't match, returns -1.
function parse_time(s) {
    return match(s, /^(([0-9]+)w)?(([0-9]+)d)?(([0-9]+)h)?(([0-9]+)m)?(([0-9]+)s)?$/, m) ? m[10] + m[8] * 60 + m[6] * 3600 + m[4] * 86400 + m[2] * 604800 : -1;
}

{
  $(++NF) = parse_time($1);
  print;
}
```

You can then sort the output on the new column and subsequently remove it:

```sh
gawk -f parse-times.awk input.txt | sort -n -k 2,2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Comment: If my input contains multiple columns, how do I specify which column contains duration?

Comment: @Kossak Unfortunately, this *specific* solution is incompatible with multicolumn input because `FPAT` supersedes Awk’s usual column splitting. Instead, you can resort to Awk’s other regular expression matching tools. I’ll draft such a solution in a moment…

Answer (score 5):

#### First version - FPAT is used

```
gawk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="[0-9]+|[smhd]";
}
/s/ { factor = 1 }
/m/ { factor = 60 }
/h/ { factor = 3600 }
/d/ { factor = 86400 }
{
    print $1 * factor, $0;
}' input.txt | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
```

> **FPAT**  -      A regular expression describing the contents of the fields
>   in a record.  When set, gawk
>                      parses the input into fields, where the fields match the regular expression, instead of
>                      using the value of the **FS** variable as the field separator.

#### Second version

I was surprised to discover, that without `FPAT` it also works.
It is caused the number conversion mechanism of `awk` - [How awk Converts Between Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers), namely:

> A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix of the string as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3" converts to 1,000, and "25fix" has a numeric value of 25. Strings that can’t be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.

```
gawk '
/s/ { factor = 1 }
/m/ { factor = 60 }
/h/ { factor = 3600 }
/d/ { factor = 86400 }
{
    print $0 * factor, $0;
}' input.txt | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Input (changed a little bit)**

```
1s
122s
1h
2h
1m
2m
2s
1d
1m
```

**Output**

**Note:** 122 seconds more than 2 minutes, so it sorted after 2m.

```
1s
2s
1m
1m
2m
122s
1h
2h
1d
```

Comment: +1 I like the clever use of `FPAT`. This could easily be expanded to accept and handle time values like `1d3h10m40s`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I looked to your `awk` answer and discovered interesting fact: strings like `1s`, `3d`, `4m` converting to the integer by `awk` itself, without problems. So, they can be used for math operations directly - without splitting by regex. I was added second version of the solution and an explanation of this behaviour too.

Answer (score 4):

If you only have times in the format of your question:

`sort -k 1.2,1.2 -k 1.1,1.1 <file>`

Where `<file>` is the file your data resides in. This command sorts on the second letter (ascending) and then sorts on the first letter (ascending). This works because it just so happes that the ordering of the letters for the time units (d > h > m > s) is exactly the order we want (day > hours > minutes > seconds).

Comment: Just like the other (now deleted) answer, this assumes durations are single-digit...

Comment: @don_crissti I answered the question because in the worst case I can just delete and in the best case this is exactly what he was looking for. I thought this was a better approach than waiting for an edit of the question (which potentially takes a long time, so by then the question might be lost).

Answer (score 2):

Solution in Python 3:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re, fileinput

class RegexMatchIterator:
    def __init__(self, regex, string, error_on_incomplete=False):
        self.regex = regex
        self.string = string
        self.error_on_incomplete = error_on_incomplete
        self.pos = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        match = self.regex.match(self.string, self.pos)
        if match is not None:
            if match.end() > self.pos:
                self.pos = match.end()
                return match
            else:
                fmt = '{0!s} returns an empty match at position {1:d} for "{3!r}"'

        elif self.error_on_incomplete and self.pos < len(self.string):
            if isinstance(self.error_on_incomplete, str):
                fmt = self.error_on_incomplete
            else:
                fmt = '{0!s} didn\'t match the suffix {3!r} at position {1:d} of {2!r}'

        else:
            raise StopIteration(self.pos)

        raise ValueError(fmt.format(
            self.regex, self.pos, self.string, self.string[self.pos:]))


DURATION_SUFFIXES = { 's': 1, 'm': 60, 'h': 3600, 'd': 24*3600 }
DURATION_PATTERN = re.compile(
    '(\\d+)(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, DURATION_SUFFIXES.keys())) + ')')

def parse_duration(s):
    return sum(
        int(m.group(1)) * DURATION_SUFFIXES[m.group(2)]
        for m in RegexMatchIterator(DURATION_PATTERN, s,
            'Illegal duration string {3!r} at position {1:d}'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with fileinput.input() as f:
        result = sorted((l.rstrip('\n') for l in f), key=parse_duration)
    for item in result:
        print(item)
```

As you can see I spent about ⅔ of the line count towards a useful iterator over [`regex.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) results because [`regex.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.finditer) doesn't tie matches to the beginning of the current region and there are no other suitable ways to iterate over match results. **grrr**

Answer (score 2):

A very good answer here [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) but I can confirm that doesn't recognize all the cases with s/m/h/d:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase=Succeeded | \
awk '{ unitvalue=$6; }; \
        $6 ~ /[0-9]+s/ { m=1 }; \
        $6 ~ /[0-9]+m/ { m=60 }; \
        $6 ~ /[0-9]+h/ { m=3600 }; \
        $6 ~ /[0-9]+d/ { m=86400 }; \
        { \
            sub("[smhd]","",unitvalue); \
            unitvalue=unitvalue*m; \
            print unitvalue, $1, $4, $6, $8; \
        }' | \
    sort -rn -k1,1 | \
    awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' | column -t
```

is giving me bad results:

```
0 NAMESPACE STATUS AGE
11923200 istio-system Completed 138d
11923200 istio-system Completed 138d
11923200 istio-system Completed 138d
4579200 kube-system Completed 53d
4579200 kube-system Completed 53d
11318400 kube-system Completed 131d
11318400 kube-system Completed 131d
11318400 kube-system Completed 131d
18144000 kube-system Completed 210d
11318400 kube-system Completed 131d
2160000 prod Completed 2d5h
104400 prod Completed 29h
1872000 prod Completed 5h20m
```

looks like when you try to count 5h20m gets crazy, I tried other solution and the values are fine but impossible to pass to the rest of the command:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase=Succeeded | awk '{print $6}' | \
> gawk '
> /s/ { factor = 1 }
> /m/ { factor = 60 }
> /h/ { factor = 3600 }
> /d/ { factor = 86400 }
> {
>   print $0 * factor, $0;
> }'
0 AGE
11923200 138d
11923200 138d
11923200 138d
4579200 53d
4579200 53d
11318400 131d
11318400 131d
11318400 131d
18144000 210d
11318400 131d
172800 2d5h
104400 29h
18000 5h30m
```

Note that:

```
1872000 prod Completed 5h20m
```

vs

```
18000 5h30m
```

Comment: this is still not correct as 18000 == 5h

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @hauke-laging's fine answer I wanted to expand some additional details to scale up his answer for use with a more broad set of problems. His solution assumes the input would be a single column. If you have a random field that you'd like to perform the same operation on you can do the following.

#### Sample data

Say I have the following output that was generated by this command:

```
$ oc get po -o wide --all-namespaces | grep ContainerCreat
ns8 pod8   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 2m  <none> ocp-app-01b.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns9 pod9   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 2m  <none> ocp-app-01b.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns1 pod1   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 45s <none> ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns2 pod2   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 58s <none> ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns3 pod3   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 58s <none> ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns5 pod5   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 1m  <none> ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns6 pod6   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 2m  <none> ocp-app-01g.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns4 pod4   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 1m  <none> ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
ns7 pod7   0/1 ContainerCreating 0 2m  <none> ocp-app-01b.lab1.somedom.local      <none>
```

You could use the following to select the 6th field, `$6`, and then perform the operation that was shown in the other answer. The method is simple yet effective.

You're basically taking the column of interest, `$6` in this example, and performing a calculation on it using the appropriate conversion factor based on the units present.

Once converted, the calculation is added as part of the output, used to sort the output correctly based on that column's expanded form value, and then deleted in the final output of column data.

```
$ oc get po -o wide --all-namespaces | \
    grep ContainerCreat | \
    awk '{ unitvalue=$6; }; \
            $6 ~ /[0-9]+s/ { m=1 }; \
            $6 ~ /[0-9]+m/ { m=60 }; \
            $6 ~ /[0-9]+h/ { m=3600 }; \
            $6 ~ /[0-9]+d/ { m=86400 }; \
            { \
                sub("[smhd]","",unitvalue); \
                unitvalue=unitvalue*m; \
                print unitvalue, $1, $4, $6, $8; \
            }' | \
    sort -rn -k1,1 | \
    awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' | column -t
```

#### Example

```
$ oc get po -o wide --all-namespaces | \
        grep ContainerCreat | \
        awk '{ unitvalue=$6; }; \
                $6 ~ /[0-9]+s/ { m=1 }; \
                $6 ~ /[0-9]+m/ { m=60 }; \
                $6 ~ /[0-9]+h/ { m=3600 }; \
                $6 ~ /[0-9]+d/ { m=86400 }; \
                { \
                    sub("[smhd]","",unitvalue); \
                    unitvalue=unitvalue*m; \
                    print unitvalue, $1, $4, $6, $8; \
                }' | \
        sort -rn -k1,1 | \
        awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' | column -t

 ns1 ContainerCreating 45s ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local
 ns2 ContainerCreating 58s ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local
 ns3 ContainerCreating 58s ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local
 ns4 ContainerCreating 1m  ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local
 ns5 ContainerCreating 1m  ocp-app-01i.lab1.somedom.local
 ns6 ContainerCreating 2m  ocp-app-01g.lab1.somedom.local
 ns7 ContainerCreating 2m  ocp-app-01b.lab1.somedom.local
 ns8 ContainerCreating 2m  ocp-app-01b.lab1.somedom.local
 ns9 ContainerCreating 2m  ocp-app-01b.lab1.somedom.local
```

Notice in the final output that the data is sorted by the original `$6` column in numeric order based on time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code fragments that works with multiple units within single value (e.g. 3h15m20s) to convert into seconds:

```
$ ruby -ne 'multipliers = {"h"=> 3600, "m"=> 60, "s"=> 1}; 
    p $_.scan(/(\d+)(\D)/).reduce(0) { |sum, pair|
         sum + pair[0].to_i*multipliers[pair[1]] }'
```